# Interpolating PG array in raw SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a Rails (5.2) app with PG (10) as the database, I need to perform a raw SQL query.

In the query, I need to add a`WHERE` clause that checks the `qp.id` is among `project.qp_ids` which are stored as an array of strings.

```
t.text :qp_ids, array: true, default: []
```

I have tried several solutions, among which the following

```
" ... WHERE qp.id = ANY #{project.qp_ids}"
" ... WHERE qp.id = ANY #{project.qp_ids.join(', ')}"
" ... WHERE qp.id = ANY ARRAY(#{project.qp_ids.join(', '))}"
" ... WHERE qp.id = IN (#{project.qp_ids.join(', ')})"
```

But all produce a `PG::SyntaxError`.

What is the right way to interpolate a PG array?

**UPDATE1**

The code below works but is very ugly,

```
" ... WHERE qp.id = IN (#{self.quality_process_ids.map {|id| "'#{id}'"}.join(',')})"
```

Comment: Could you show migrations for tables from your query?

Comment: What do you mean? As far as the query's concern the table has a row named `id`.

Comment: In your query you interpolate ```project.qp_ids``` as Ruby string, and ```qp.id``` as a column ```id``` of table ```qp```. It's hard to say what you want to get. Are ```qp``` and ```products``` tables in PG? What are their fields?

Comment: `qp.id` is a column and `project.qp_ids` is the attribute `qp_ids` of the ActiveRecord `project` passed to the method responsible to build the query. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this with interpolation? ActiveRecord deals with things like `where('id = any(array[?])', project.qp_ids)` just fine. If you do need to build this by hand then you need to properly quote each element of `qp_ids` *before* you join them with commas and you'll need an extra set of parentheses  (i.e. `qp.id = any(array[...])`).

Comment: @muistooshort This is part of a composed query, different clauses (strings) are joined together to get the final query according to some conditions. As far as I know, building the query "by hand" is the only option I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't using `IN` be simpler?

```
" ... WHERE qp.id IN (#{project.qp_ids.join(',')})"
```

To deal with string quoting, you can use ActiveRecord's [sanitization](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html) directly

```
your_model_instance.sanitize_sql_array(["project.qp_ids IN (?)", project.qp_ids])
 => "project.qp_ids IN ('foo','bar')"
```

to generate the condition which you may use in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Tried also that (forgot to add in my initial question). Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  It reutrns `WHERE qp.id IN (7EE488E9-20AA-4263-8F4A-3548999F77A6,7EE488E9-20AA-4263-8F4A-3548999F77A3)"` but the values must be within `'`.

Comment: Updated for strings, originally I assumed ids are integers.

Comment: Removed the ugly version, kept the sanitization one then

Comment: Thanks, ActiveRecord's sanitization makes it look better.

Comment: You can still use the "= any" syntax if desired: `["qp.id = any(array[?])", project.qp_ids]`. AFAIK PostgreSQL will convert `in (list)` to `= any(array[list])` internally anyway. Anyway, this is the right approach.